# Custom LDAP search with Grails SPRING/LDAP Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, ldap

I am using these two plugins for LDAP authentification in my Grails application:

```
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.7.2
plugins.spring-security-ldap=1.0.5
```

However, is it possible to use the ldap plugin for custom ldap search **outside of the authentication process**? Like search in different trees etc? Or do I have to use a different plugin?

Thanks